# not able to propagate AWS lambda error to client

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have lambda functions defined - here is shorten an example:

```
export const createEmptyStock: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2<
  APIGatewayProxyResult
> = async (event: any) => {
  try {
    
    throw new exceptions.MissingAttribute("test error message");
    
    return utils.createSuccessJsonResponse({
      status: "success",
      data: stock,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    console.error(e.message);
    console.error(e.stack);

    return utils.createErrorJsonResponse({
      status: "failed",
      errorMsg: e.message,
      errorStack: e.stack,
    });
  }
};
```

here is the util file, which I use to create the responses for the lambda functions:

```
export const createGatewayResponse = ({
  statusCode,
  body,
}: {
  statusCode: number;
  body: string;
}) => {
  let response = {
    statusCode,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true, // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
    },
    body,
  };
  return response;
};

export const createSuccessResponse = (body: string) =>
  createGatewayResponse({ statusCode: 200, body });

export const createErrorResponse = (body: string) =>
  createGatewayResponse({ statusCode: 500, body });

export const createSuccessJsonResponse = (body: object) =>
  createGatewayResponse({
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });

export const createErrorJsonResponse = (body: object) =>
  createGatewayResponse({
  statusCode: 500,
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
});
```

after deploying and running this, I do see the errors in the cloudWatch messages, but on the front end side which I use axios to call - I don't see the error details. Here is the sample call on the client side using axios.

client call:

```
export async function createEmptyStock({
  productId,
  accountId,
  userId,
}: {
  productId: string;
}) {
  try {
    const queryUrl = `${aws_url}/new?arg1=${productId}`;
    const { data } = await axios.post(queryUrl);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.toJSON());
  }
}
```

the client console output:

```
{
code: undefined
columnNumber: undefined
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
description: undefined
fileName: undefined
lineNumber: undefined
message: "Request failed with status code 500"
name: "Error"
number: undefined
stack: "Error: Request failed with status code 500\n    at createError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:214546:15)\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:214813:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:213873:7)"
status: 500
}
```

I used CDK to create the lambda function:

```
const lambdaFunc = new lambdaNodejs.NodejsFunction(
  this,
  lambdaConstructName,
  {
    entry: lambdaPath,
    handler: handlerName ? handlerName : "handler",
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    layers: lambdaLayers,
  environment: {
    TABLE_NAME: this.stocksTable.tableName,
    PARTITION_KEY: this.stocksTablePartitionKey,
    SORT_KEY: this.stocksTableSortKey,
  },
  bundling: {
    minify: false,
  },
  }
);

gatewayResource.addMethod(
  resourceMethod,
  new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(lambdaFunc)
);
```

Comment: Is axios client expected to return the response of the failed API call? The client console output looks like some custom axios error information. Can you share raw HTTP response data from API call?

Comment: I forgot to answer my own question, you have to return a status code like 400 to make it work. Aws gateway handles 500 errors differently